# What is the meaning of (unsigned char *)&variable_name?

Tags: c, stm32f4discovery

what is the meaning of (unsigned char*)&ch in the following function call ?

```
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle, (unsigned char *)&ch, 1, 0xFFFF);

      HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Transmit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, unsigned char *pData, int Size, long Timeout)
     {
       /*...........Function Body ........*/
     }
```

Comment: Which part of the expression do you have problems understanding? The address-of operator? The type-casting? Something else?

Answer (score 3):

`&ch` is an address of some variable, type is unknown given this code. `(unsigned int*)&ch` is simply casting the result of this expression to a pointer to `int`.

Comment: You're right, I was imprecise here a little. Editing.

Answer (score 2):

It takes the address of the variable `ch` using the address-of operator `&`. The resulting address is then converted (cast) to the type `unsigned int *`, i.e. a pointer to an unsigned int. This only makes sense if

1. The type of `ch` was not `unsigned int` to begin with
2. The size of `ch` is at least as large as the size of `unsigned int`
3. The called function accepts an `unsigned int *` argument

Since we can see that the type of the argument is in fact `uint8_t *`, this is very likely a bug. The cast should either be removed (if `ch` is of type `uint8_t` already, which it should be) or changed to `uint8_t *`. Also, the function's parameter should be `const`, a transmit function shouln't change its argument.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a function that takes an argument of type  `unsigned int *`.

You have an object of type `int` and you want to pass a pointer to this object the function.

```
int ch = 42;
```

Then `&ch` get you an `int *` to the `int` object. You cannot pass `&ch` directly to your function as `&ch` is of type `int *` but the function wants a `unsigned int *`, so you convert it to `unsigned int *` with a cast:

```
(unsigned int *) &ch
```